# Django's BooleanField showing incorrect value in edit mode

Tags: python, mysql, django

DJango: 1.24
DB: MySQL
Column Type: Bit
Code: models.BooleanField(db_column='InStock')

The checkbox always shows checked no matter what the value is (1 or 0). The value gets saved correctly but when it renders the edit page, it always checked.

Any pointers?

Comment: What fragment of code are you rendering it with?

Answer (score 0):

You haven't provided much details so I'm guessing that you mean that you have a form and it doesn't have `required=False` set for the BooleanField.